# Is it possible to pass interface obj to interface{} type?

Tags: pointers, go, types, interface, go-interface

I'm new to golang and I want to implement an overloaded method something similar to C++ overloading, and my code looks something like this:

```
type someStruct struct {
    val  int
    some string
}

type object interface {
    toByte()
}

// someStruct implementing an object interface
func (s *someStruct) toByte() {
}

func overload(overLoadedObj interface{}) {

    switch str := overLoadedObj .(type) {
    case string:
        fmt.Println("string : ", str)
    case int:
        fmt.Println("int : ", str)
    case object: //* It doesn't come here at all*
        fmt.Println("interface obj", str)
    }
}

func main() {
    overload("hello")
    overload(5)
    overload(someStruct{val: 5, some: "say"})
}
```

So the question is:

How to make sure that whoever implements **object interface** will fall in at **case object** type ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "problem" is that `someStruct.toByte()` has a pointer receiver. This means the method `toByte()` belongs to the type `*someStruct` and not to `someStruct`. So `someStruct` does not implement `object`, only `*someStruct`. And you pass a value of `someStruct` to `overload()`.

Pass a value of `*someStruct`, and you'll get what you want:

```
overload(&someStruct{val: 5, some: "say"})
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/d8hOdEpJKW)):

```
string :  hello
int :  5
interface obj &{5 say}
```

Relevant section from the spec: [Method sets](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets):

> A type may have a *method set* associated with it. The method set of an [interface type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) is its interface. The method set of any other type `T` consists of all [methods](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations) declared with receiver type `T`. The method set of the corresponding [pointer type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types) `*T` is the set of all methods declared with receiver `*T` or `T` (that is, it also contains the method set of `T`).

#### Behind the scenes

Note that behind the scenes when you call `overload()` like this:

```
overload(&someStruct{val: 5, some: "say"})
```

This will wrap the `*someStruct` pointer value in an `interface{}` value (because `overload()` has a parameter of `interface{}` type), and not in an interface value of type `object`.

Inside `overload()`, the [type switch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches) will check types in the listed order. And when it reaches `case object`, it will see that the value wrapped in the `overLoadedObj` parameter does implement `object` so this case will be executed.

Comment: Awesome... Thank u very much.